# Как составить sql запрос на обновление разных полей таблицы в зависимости от значения конкретного поля

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно ли одним запросом сделать такое?

Если `date2 IS NOT NULL`:
`UPDATE table SET date1 = date2, date2 = NULL, status = 1 WHERE id IN (123,124,125)`
Если же `date2 = NULL`:
`UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id IN (123,124,125)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пример**

Если date2 не NULL, данные из date2 были копированы в date1, а потом date2 был назначен NULL.

Если date2 = NULL , то date1 не трогаем

> ```
> create table table1
> (
>    id int, 
>    date1 date,
>    date2 date,
>    status int
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into table1 (id,date1,date2,status) values
> (123, '2018-07-01','2018-07-20',0),
> (124, '2018-07-07',null,0)
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | date1      | date2      | status
> --: | :--------- | :--------- | -----:
> 123 | 2018-07-01 | 2018-07-20 |      0
> 124 | 2018-07-07 | null       |      0
> ```

> ```
>  UPDATE table1
>  SET 
>    date1 = IF(date2 is null,date1,date2),
>    date2 = NULL, status = 1 
> WHERE id IN (123,124,125)
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | date1      | date2 | status
> --: | :--------- | :---- | -----:
> 123 | 2018-07-20 | null  |      1
> 124 | 2018-07-07 | null  |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d9e6731f3bd80abff9f941950b5dbfd)*